# How can I programmatically click on "Buy" button in automated Android in-app billing testing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, automated-tests, in-app-billing

I am writing automated testing code (using *ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2*) to test an app that involves in-app billing version 2 (subscriptions). I need help on figuring out how to programmatically get my testing code to click on the "Accept and Buy" button that appears inside the "**Pay with credit card/Secured by Google Wallet**" dialog which is supposedly created by some Google SDK code.

I can get the testing code to click on other buttons that are created by my own code/acitivty, usually by accessing the buttons from its parent activity or view, and then call the `.performClick()` method on the button. But this "Buy" button is not reachable from any activities as far as I know.

It appears this dialog may be created by `com.google.android.finsky.activities.IabActivity`  based on the logcat output. I used an ActivityMonitor watching this activity, but it was never triggered. If you can help either directly, or point me to the relevant Google SDK source code that's responsible for creating the "Pay with credit card" dialog or the source for the `com.google.android.finsky.activities.IabActivity` class, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 3):

Normally you can't instrument Activities outside of your own package.

You'd have to use the UI Automator framework to click the Buy button.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Christopher. I managed to use UI Automation to get the effect I want. I had to write a shell script to call my Instrumentation Test first, which brings up the Buy dialog. Then call
*adb shell uiautomator runtest* to launch the UI automation code to click on the "Buy" button. Not sure how to sync between them so I just use some sleep code to time the click. Here is the UI automation code:

```
    UiDevice dev = getUiDevice();
    // wait for buy button to appear 
    while (true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000l);
            UiObject okButton = new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Accept & buy").className("android.widget.Button"));
            okButton.click();
            break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }   
    dev.waitForIdle();
```

Comment: Nice. Though I believe you can use the `UiWatcher` class to wait for the button to appear. There's an example here: http://everybodytests.blogspot.de/2012/11/uiautomator-and-watchers-adding-async.html

Answer (score 1):

Using **uiautomator**, this is the best I got:

```
device.findObject(new UiSelector().resourceId("com.android.vending:id/continue_button")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are suggestion for making Testcase for Button click in android.

You need to make ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 for your Activity then do following .

Initialize your button in

```
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        mainActivity = getActivity();

        btnAcceptBuy= (Button) mainActivity.findViewById(R.id.btnaccept_buy);
    }



public void testFragmentKeypad(){

      AppLog.showLogE("TEST", "Keypad");

      TouchUtils.clickView(this, btnAcceptBuy);

  }
```

By this way you can perform click testing of your button in android.

Comment: R.id.btnaccept_buy is its full package name android.R.id.btnaccept_buy ? But that name is not valid according to Eclipse autocompletion.  The problem I see is this button does not belong to my main activity, it's only reachable from an activity class in Google SDK or some dialog class.

Comment: Are you using In App API 2?

Comment: Yes I am using IAB v2 because I have to use subscriptions. Sigh. So in v3 this btnaccept_buy can be reached from my main activity? Maybe I should wait for v3 subscription. thanks.

Comment: actually i have just give you example id of button because i though that you have your own Button declare in your Activity .For this com.google.android.finsky.activities.IabActivity i also have to check.

Comment: Finsky was the code name for the beta Honeycomb market.  http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=995371

Answer (score 0):

```
    UiAutomation uiAutomation = new UiAutomation(Looper.getMainLooper(), new UiAutomationConnection());
    uiAutomation.setOnAccessibilityEventListener(new UiAutomation.OnAccessibilityEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
            if (event.getEventType() == TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED) {
                if ("com.google.android.finsky".contentEquals(event.getPackageName())) {
                    if ("com.google.android.finsky.activities.IabActivity".contentEquals(event.getClassName())) {
                        final List<AccessibilityNodeInfo> accessibilityNodeInfosByViewId = event.getSource().findAccessibilityNodeInfosByViewId("<package name>:id/<control id>"); // find by layout inspector
                        if (accessibilityNodeInfosByViewId.size() > 0) {
                            accessibilityNodeInfosByViewId.get(0).performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    uiAutomation.connect();
    //release when exit
    uiAutomation.disconnect();
```